# Is "cleaning staff" derogatory in English?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, style, euphemism

In my native language, when we refer to cleaning staff, we use the word *lokalvårdare* (literally 'room carer' or 'premises carer') rather than *städare* (literally 'cleaner'), since *städare* has come to be looked upon as somewhat derogatory. Now I'm wondering if the same applies to English, so that there is a more "proper" word or phrase to be used for cleaning staff – and, if so, what this word/phrase is.

Comment: In my UK office there is nothing derogatory saying someone is a 'cleaner'. We invited our cleaner to come to our Christmas meal and she was a big hit with everyone. The office building people call them 'building services staff' but she says 'I am your cleaner'. It is an important and responsible job.

Comment: It is worth noting that employers have generally given important-sounding titles to junior workers in order to make their jobs sound more significant. **An engineer** was once widely (although not exclusively) understood to refer to a person with a university or technical qualification. Today drain cleaners frequently have titles such as **sanitary engineers**. And to be called a manager signifies very little. Having said this, I completely agree with Michael Harvey and James K.

Comment: Our cleaner fixed a laser printer paper jam once, when nobody else dared to open the thing, and there was a 3 day wait for the IT guy. Since then lots of people ask her opinion about things. She's usually right. She drove buses in Poland but doesn't want to do that here.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I must say, I absolutely love your examples :)

Comment: @RonaldSole - "An engineer was once widely (although not exclusively) understood to refer to a person with a university or technical qualification" My father was an electrical engineer and it bugged him if people thought he was an 'electrician'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Cleaner" or "cleaning staff" is not derogatory.

While being a cleaner is important, it isn't a high ranking or highly paid job. Nevertheless, calling someone whose job is cleaning "a cleaner" is acceptable.

Of course, if someone has a higher-ranking job, such as a premises manager, or a site conservator, then calling them a "cleaner" might be rude, because you are misdescribing their job.